# External URL for .ifc file in web-ifc-viewer

Tags: ifc

In my project, I want to include a viewer like the one in the web-ifc-viewer example
(https://github.com/IFCjs/web-ifc-viewer/tree/master/example).
The example has all the features I need, and I'm in a rush to complete my MVP. The only change I need to make is to use an external URL from my CDN for the .ifc file, like 'cdn.mycdn.com/file.ifc'. Is there a quick solution for this?